# safari embedded paypal fails - Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options

Tags: paypal, payment

I just discovered my embedded payments implementation does not work in Safari.
For Safari, I'm getting this error in the console:
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options

I cannot find a way to work around this.

Note that the implementation works fine in IE, FF, and Chrome (well, FF has a diff issue but this part seems to work).

Here are the calls (edited for clarity):

```
var urlBase = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay";
var payKey = "AP-12345ABCDE6789012";
flow_Javascript = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow( { trigger:null, expType:"light" } );
flow_Javascript.startFlow( urlBase + "?payKey=" + payKey );
```

FYI this is returned in the console:

> Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading
>   'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/expresscheckoutincontextremembermeflow?execution=e1s1':
>   'NONE' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.

Comment: The error message you are seeing is at the request header level (PayPal uses X-Frame to avoid embedding within iframes, which can lead to all sorts of clickjacking hacks). However, this does not affect your javascript functionality in any way shape or form. 

Are you getting any other errors in the console? (Specific to javascript?)

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out? I have the same problem right now!

Comment: Any resolutions to this problem?? - this is causing me issues!!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and adding try/catch block helped:

```
try { 
  flow_Javascript.startFlow( urlBase + "?payKey=" + payKey );
} catch (err) {
  // add some error logging here
}
```